--no-build option doesn't work with dotnet pack command
I'm using following Azure devops pipeline tasks to create nuget package.
task-1 : build the projects
task-2 : Digital sign the binaries.
task-3 : Without rebuilding the binaries, Create nuget package with previously built binaries with digital signature.
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) /p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    projects: '**/PdfReport/*.csproj'

- template: SignFilesWithAzureSignTool.yml
  parameters:
    filesToSignPatterns:
      - RegEx: '.*\SHS.SMI.ITS.*.dll'
        BasePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet custom'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    projects: '**\PdfReport\*.csproj'
    custom: pack
    arguments: '--no-build'

Getting following error
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.307\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(175,5): error NETSDK1085: The 'NoBuild' property was set to true but the 'Build' target was invoked.
How to Achieve this?
Explained the detailsAbove.

I can only reproduce the same error when adding the TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage as mentioned in this issue. Please check whether you are having the same target. If so, try the workaround shared here. If you are in other situation, please share your .csproj file.

To fix the NETSDK1085 error, you're getting it because --no-build conflicts with the build being triggered in the pack step. You don't need a rebuild—just pack the signed binaries.
Update your last task like this:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Pack signed binaries'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    projects: '**/PdfReport/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-build --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

This will skip the build and pack the existing signed binaries directly.

It seems that the NETSDK1085 error usually occurs when the packed project has project references.
In certain situations, when packing a project, it will re-build the project references of it even if the '--no-build' option set.  You can try to use the MSBuild property "BuildProjectReferences=false" on the "dotnet pack" command to avoid re-building the project references.
In addition, to set the version of the packed package, you should use the MSBuild property "PackageVersion={version-number}" on the "dotnet pack" command.
See below sample as reference:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '-c $(BuildConfiguration)'
    projects: '**/PdfReport/*.csproj'

- template: SignFilesWithAzureSignTool.yml
  parameters:
    filesToSignPatterns:
      - RegEx: '.*/SHS.SMI.ITS.*.dll'
        BasePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    projects: '**/PdfReport/*.csproj'
    custom: pack
    arguments: '--no-build -c $(BuildConfiguration) -p:BuildProjectReferences=false -p:PackageVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber)'

